# getVideoCommentFeed (Zend Gdata Youtube API - PHP) - obtain most-liked comments

Tags: php, comments, youtube-api, zend-gdata

I'm trying to obtain the "most liked" comments from a video of my choice (top 2 comments) for display, using the Youtube API.  I'm using Zend Gdata package to obtain all of my vid-data.  I can't seem to figure out if this function exists (in fact, I can't see how to see a rating of a comment at all...).

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to find the Top Comments on a video, the rating data for comments is not included in the YouTube API (2.0) at the moment.

[Here is the open issue.](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=660&q=Top%20comments%20label%3aAPI-YouTube&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary)

---

References:

- https://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/3feda3bc9ab5a852/28e6f61fac1d83b0
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments#Retrieve_comments

Answer (score 0):

YouTube API 2.0 (current) and 3.0 (beta) both do not support the ability to request the rating associated with a comment.

[Jeff Posnick](https://plus.google.com/+jeffposnick/about) who works on the YouTube API Developer Relations Team commented on August 24th, 2012:

> Unfortunately, this is something that the engineering team confirmed will not be added to the API.

He gave no reason why and has closed the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=660) as *WontFix*.